# Max WebRTC connection using RTCDataChannel

Tags: webrtc

I want to make/experiment with a P2P network running on browsers (WebSocket and WebRTC for inter-browser communication) as well as on servers for signaling using WebSockets.

I read online that the max WebRTC connection is theoretically 256 on Chromium, but only around 6 practically. Most resources mentioned WebRTC with video calls, therefore, what is the practical limit using RTCDataChannel which consumes less bandwidth, at least in my use case?

Comment: What is the 'max' you mean? Max amount of connections? Or are we talking about bandwidth?

Comment: I am talking about the max amount of connections in average. If bandwidth is the only factor affecting the limit, it is possible to connect to many RTC peers (> 64). So what is the max amount of connections in practice? I am thinking about setting up a test, but it will be great if someone already done it.